# PHP, job queue such as CRON

Tags: php, apache, cron, zend-server

I'd like to have a job queue such as CRON for my application so i could launch automatically a script every day at same time to calculate some data and store them.

I'm actually using zend server free edition for development (localhost only) and i just saw that zend server professional edition have a job queue feature. But i must say it is a bit expansive. I'm still thinking about it but i'm also trying to see other options for implementing a job queue in our development environment.

Our server is actually using Windows server.

I must say i only know about development so i might say some absurdities.

Should i install Linux instead of Windows server and install an Apache server to be able to use CRON.

Or actually with zend server free edition i might be able to set up an environment where i can use CRON (in my windows server environment)?

From what i understood i might need to install SSH2 library.

Comment: On windows you can use the `Task scheduler` to run tasks at given times: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Comment: Okay, with the task scheduler, may i be able to run a php function? such as a controller in an MVC architecture?

Comment: you need to be able to run PHP via the command line (CLI) and investigate the PHP framework that you use whether controllers can be run via CLI. This may be useful: [12158183/runing-php-scripts-locally-though-task-manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158183/runing-php-scripts-locally-though-task-manager)